# Sum values in df1 based on .eq() in df2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to sum up some market volumes based on equal prices in, let's say, 6 hours of 2017.

I have a DataFrame, df1 (market_volumes), that contains the market volumes in some areas. Then I have another DataFrame, df2 (mFRR_price), which contains some market prices.

```
df1
             Date  NO1 Up  NO1 Down  NO2 Up  ...  DK1 Up  DK1 Down  DK2 Up  DK2 Down
35062  31-12-2020    54.0       0.0   214.0  ...    33.0       0.0    31.0       0.0
35063  31-12-2020     3.0       0.0   121.0  ...   125.0       0.0    21.0       0.0
35064  31-12-2020     0.0     -28.0     0.0  ...     0.0      -9.0     0.0       0.0
35065  31-12-2020     0.0     -83.0     0.0  ...     0.0       0.0     0.0       0.0
35066  31-12-2020     0.0     -80.0     0.0  ...     0.0     -55.0     0.0       0.0
35067  31-12-2020     0.0     -42.0     0.0  ...    79.0       0.0    23.0       0.0
```

```
df2
             Date  NO1 Up  NO2 Up  NO3 Up  ...  SE4 Up  FI Up  DK1 Up  DK2 Up
35062  31-12-2020    47.4    47.4    27.2  ...    61.1   61.1    94.1    94.1
35063  31-12-2020    31.0    31.0    25.7  ...    58.0   35.3    89.4    89.4
35064  31-12-2020    24.8    24.8    24.8  ...    54.5   24.8    56.7    56.7
35065  31-12-2020    24.8    24.8    24.8  ...    51.2   28.0    52.4    52.4
35066  31-12-2020    24.6    24.6    24.6  ...    45.8   26.6    51.9    51.9
35067  31-12-2020    24.1    24.1    23.3  ...    24.1   24.1    78.7    78.7
```

Now, I want to sum up the market volumes from df1 IF the values in a row in df2 are equal to the value in column "NO1 UP".

i.e., I am looking for a way to end up with a new DataFrame that would result in:

```
df3
             Date  NO1 Up  NO1 Down  NO2 Up  ...  DK1 Up  DK1 Down  DK2 Up  DK2 Down    SUM
35062  31-12-2020    54.0       0.0   214.0  ...    33.0       0.0    31.0       0.0    (54+214)
35063  31-12-2020     3.0       0.0   121.0  ...   125.0       0.0    21.0       0.0    (3+121)
35064  31-12-2020     0.0     -28.0     0.0  ...     0.0      -9.0     0.0       0.0    etc.
35065  31-12-2020     0.0     -83.0     0.0  ...     0.0       0.0     0.0       0.0
35066  31-12-2020     0.0     -80.0     0.0  ...     0.0     -55.0     0.0       0.0
35067  31-12-2020     0.0     -42.0     0.0  ...    79.0       0.0    23.0       0.0
```

... because it locates the area prices that are equal and sums the market volumes on those locations in the DataFrame.

I've been working on this:

```
market_volumes['sum'] = mFRR_price.eq(mFRR_price['NO1 Up'], axis=0).mul(mFRR_price['NO1 Up'], axis=0).sum(axis=1)
```

But it sums the values in df2 in puts it in the df1. I need the POSITIONS in df2, but the values from df1.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df3['SUM'] = df3['NO1 Up'] + df3['NO2 Up']
```

Comment: That would not nearly serve the purpose I'm looking for. I am trying to do something similar to SUMIF in excel.
I don't need the simple sum, but the sum ONLY in those hours where the price is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .loc and apply boolean indexing.

```
df1.loc[df2['NO1 Up'] == df2['NO2 Up'], 'SUM'] = df1['NO1 Up'] + df1['NO2 Up']
df1.loc[df2['NO1 Up'] != df2['NO2 Up'], 'SUM'] = 0
```

First line goes down df2's index and checks if values in columns NO1 Up and NO2 Up are equal. It then creates a column called 'SUM' - the value of this new column is dependent on the outcome of the preceding boolean.. We say if preceding boolean is true, then go to the SUM column and do the below operation:

```
= df1['NO1 Up'] + df1['NO2 Up']
```

Conversely, if the outcome false, then pandas will insert 'NaN' into your SUM column.

Not sure if you are ok with NaN values. Most are not, so the second line of code is more or less the inverse of the first... If df2['NO1 Up'] != df2['NO2 Up'], then insert integer 0 in the df1 SUM column.

Again, there are probably other ways to accomplish what you want.